# How common are UTF8 strings in X509

Tags: encoding, x.509

In theory, names in X509 certs are defined as:

```
CHOICE {
  teletexString     TeletexString   (SIZE (1..ub-state-name)),
  printableString   PrintableString (SIZE (1..ub-state-name)),
  universalString   UniversalString (SIZE (1..ub-state-name)),
  utf8String        UTF8String      (SIZE (1..ub-state-name)),
  bmpString         BMPString       (SIZE(1..ub-state-name)) }
```

But what's the current state of certificates in the world? Everything I've seen so far uses just `UTF8String` for all the fields.

I'm writing a service for signing recent CSRs generated of new Linux systems, used in internal networks only - not in the wild. Is there any risk in always outputting `UTF8String` in the signed requests and dropping any CSR which isn't using that encoding?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is actually included in [RFC 4630](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4630#section-3) and various later ones. It looks like 2003 was the last year when other encodings were relevant. These days UTF8String (or potentially PrintableString) are the answer.